# How to automate formatting excel file via a VBA module

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a module that I wrote in VBA with excel. This module formats an excel sheet and saves a new file at a specified destination. So far I've just been importing the module into the VBA project and running the script from there.

I have tried using powershell for this but it is not my strong suit and I have been running into security issues with excel.

Severally summarized module:

```
'Essentially a lot of standard excel formatting, sorting, and fill colors

'Prompts for save location
Dim Fldr As String
With Application.FileDialog(4)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    Fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Fldr & "\generated_report.xlsx", 51
```

Ideally I'd want an executable or script file that would prompt for the target excel file and then run the macro onto that file and save it in a destination, but all automatically.

The end-all be-all here would be a lightweight script file that could run without having to alter security settings within excel and could run on any machine with excel installed. Any help pointing me in the right direction for the method to use would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What have you researched/tried so far?

Comment: If you need this to be available to format any file you could put it in your personal.xlsm file and assign it to a shortcut.

Comment: I made some attempt to use powershell to automate the module process, but I started to run into some issues with excel security, what I am looking for here is more of a direction to take, I didnt want to go too far down a path that wouldnt end up working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up translating the VBA code into VBS, it opens the unformatted file and does operations onto it and then saves it as a new document. Works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Look into a VBA technique called Automation.  One way you could solve the problem is with a .vbs script that Automates to each workbook file.  You can run the .vbs script from the command line.  E.g.:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23104413/Format-and-Excel-spreadsheet-using-vbscript.html

Comment: so essentially translate my .bas file into a .vbs script?